# Check if HDMI still alive?

Tags: x11, xrandr, hdmi

I have a laptop (Aspire 3750G) and suddenly after it shut down because of overheat - I can't see my HDMI back.

`xrandr -q` returns me only LVDS-1, VGA-1, and VGA-1-2.

I'm using `nouveau` driver since Linux installed on this laptop (Ubuntu first and Arch Linux last >year) and never had HDMI issues before.

So my assumption is this is something wrong with the hardware and the question is - how can I check hardware HDMI status in Linux?

Comment: OK, not sure what was the reason but after next attempt to upgrade and reboot - suddenly HMDI went back... I love you, Linux.
What else I did - "turned off and on again" (c) `LVDS-1` and `VGA-1`.

Answer (score 1):

`xrandr` checks hardware HDMI status, if that doesn't show an `HDMI-` then there is a problem with video subsystem. Perhaps,

- the driver is corrupted, or misconfigured
- the card itself is failed to initialize
- there is a BIOS/UEFI option to enable dual-monitor or HDMI